# Do these union- and intersection-like operations have a name?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I have two sets of pairs, e.g:

$$A = \{ (a, 1), (b, 2), (c, 3) \}$$

$$B = \{ (b, 12), (c, 13), (d, 14) \}$$

I also have two operators which match the first element of pairs and return a pair of modified sets. This intersection-like operation $\cap'$ keeps only pairs that have a corresponding first element in the other set:

$$ A \cap' B = ( \{ (b, 2), (c, 3) \}, \{ (b, 12), (c, 13) \} )$$

On the other hand, this union-like operation adds new pairs to each set, taking first elements from the other set and setting the second element to zero:

$$ A \cup' B = ( \{ (a, 1), (b, 2), (c, 3), (d, 0) \}, \{ (a, 0), (b, 12), (c, 13), (d, 14) \} )$$

Are there names for these operations?

Comment: Please excuse the newbie nature of my notation and wording and feel free to make improvements.